# How do you get NVCC to include macro definition information?

Tags: macros, cuda, nvcc

Normally with gcc you can specify the level of debugging information with -g and if you use -g3 it will include preprocessor macro definitions in the executable which debuggers like gdb can read and allow you to use during debugging.  I would like to do this with nvcc for debugging CUDA programs.

I am currently working by modifying the template program in the SDK so I'm using the default Makefile and common.mk included from the Makefile.  In common.mk within the 'ifeq ($(dbg), 1)' block, I have tried the following:

- put -g3 under COMMONFLAGS
- put -g3 under NVCCFLAGS
- put -g3 under CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS
- put --compiler-options -g3 under NVCCFLAGS.

The first two give an unrecognized option error.  The second two do not seem to do the trick because when I debug using cuda-gdb I don't get the macro information.

The reason I would like to do this is because I would like to inspect some memory using the same macros the program itself uses to access that memory.  For example,

```
 #define ARROW(state, arrow) ((c_arrow_t *)(&((state)->arrows) + (arrow) * sizeof(c_arrow_t)))                                                                                                  
 #define STATE(nfa, state) ((c_state_t *)(&((nfa)->states) + (state) * sizeof(c_state_t)))
```

are some macros I use to access states and arrows of a non-deterministic finite state automaton.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to pass both -g to nvcc to set it to build with host debugging, and *also* pass -g3 to the host compiler via the -Xcompiler (or --compiler-options).

Just an observation, but you really shouldn't be using that SDK makefile for anything. It is truly evil - a crude broken hack on some autotools generated make statements, which is both unnecessarily complex and very inflexible. Even the NVIDIA developers I interact with warn not to use it.